# how to make image tilt correction by user input in matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am developing a semi user interface , in which I want to introduce a user input in which a popup window should come and asking that "do you want to tilt the image?" with yes or no option.

If I press yes again one window should open and ask me to put the required angle through which you want to rotate the figure. If I press no. program should proceed as before. I have tried like this but not working.

```
            dlgTitle    = 'Tilt correction?';
            dlgQuestion = 'Do you wish to Tilt the image?';
            choice = questdlg(dlgQuestion,dlgTitle,'Yes','No', 'Yes');
            prompt={'Enter a value of \theta (in degrees)'};
            name = 'Tilt correction';
            defaultans = {'30'};
            options.Interpreter = 'tex';
             answer = inputdlg(prompt,name,[1 40],defaultans,options);
             end
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if i am addressing the right problem, but if its "the proceed at no" issue you missed an "if"

```
dlgTitle    = 'Tilt correction?';
dlgQuestion = 'Do you wish to Tilt the image?';
choice = questdlg(dlgQuestion,dlgTitle,'Yes','No', 'Yes');
if strcmp(choice,'Yes')
   prompt={'Enter a value of \theta (in degrees)'};
   name = 'Tilt correction';
   defaultans = {'30'};
   options.Interpreter = 'tex';
   answer = inputdlg(prompt,name,[1 40],defaultans,options);
end
```

if you want to adress the [1,40] range as well you need an additional loop. but this should already work for just yes and no